# I Cannot Install SQL Server 2019 Express. It gets stuck on Offline Installation of Microsoft Machine Learning Server Components

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2019 Express on my laptop. I initially click on custom to start and everything seems to go smooth up to the point where it's at the Offline Installation of Microsoft Machine Learning Server Components section.

When I get there I get a screenshot that looks like this:

[image]

From this point on I cannot figure out what to do next. I tried creating a directory, downloading all of the files listed to that directory, and enter that directory in the Install Path line. But when I do that the Next button still is disabled.

So what is the next step?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 37):

Download the 4 cab files below (same links in your screenshot):

- [SRO_3.5.2.125_1033.cab](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2085686)
- [SRS_9.4.7.25_1033.cab](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2085792)
- [SPO_4.5.12.120_1033.cab](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2085793)
- [SPS_9.4.7.25_1033.cab](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2085685)

then, create a new folder `MLMcServer` in your C: drive `C:\MLMcServer`.

Put the 4 files there **without extracting them**

Finally, return to the installation dialog and browse to the location of the created folder `C:\MLMcServer`

Comment: Good luck, did not help for 2017 / 2019 versions

Comment: its work on v2019

Answer (score 8):

You, No need the Machine Learning Services – Offline. you can untick  Machine Learning Services in the feature session. Otherwise, you need that. You have to download the correct files that match the version of SQL you're installing. The files you're using from that link provided will not work since it is an older version and you are installing 2019, have you tried: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-ml-component-install-without-internet-access?view=sql-server-ver15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-ml-component-install-without-internet-access?view=sql-server-ver15) Those are the current files for 2019 RTM.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using a SQL Server installer in another language should know that downloading the files and placing them in a folder for the installer to detect will not work. What worked for me is to use the English installer.

If you want you can use the SQL Server installer in another language, but uncheck the features of Microsoft Machine Learning Server; When you have finished installing the SQL Server instance and the other features, you must now run the installer in English, select that you want to add features to an existing instance, mark the missing features of Microsoft Machine Learning Server and go through the steps of downloading the files and place them in a folder, select the folder where the four files are and the Next button will work correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Downloading the .cab files, does not work.

Downloading the .iso files, does not work.

Only solution is moving the client to mySQL, where they should have been all along.

Not being lead around the nose by Microsoft.